# How to display list values in webservice class?

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, list, apex-webservice

When the user enters his name from third party application, The user needs to get all the records(Account,Contact,Lead) matching the text entered by him.

I have used sosl for this purpose.But I cant able to show the fetched values from the list(account,contact,lead).

I am getting an error in this class.

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: List at line 22 column 23

```
global class exposewsdl{
    global class requestKT{
        webservice string inputName; 
    }
    global class responseOfWs{
        webservice string name;
        webservice string errorFound;
    }
    webservice static responseOfWs getCaseDetailsFromcsNum(requestKT csNum){
        try{
            List<Opportunity> optyList =New List<Opportunity>();
             List<contact> conList= New List<contact>();
             List<account> accList=New List<account>();

             String searchStr1 = '*'+csNum.inputName+'*';
             String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' +searchStr1  + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  Account (Name),Contact(name),Lead(name)';
            List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
            accList = ((List<Account>)searchList[0]);
            conList  = ((List<contact>)searchList[1]);
            optyList = ((List<Opportunity>)searchList[2]);
            responseOfWs res = new responseOfWs();
           res.name= accList.name;
            return res;
        }catch(Exception e){
            responseOfWs res = new responseOfWs();
            res.errorFound = e.getMessage();
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```

**Please help me how to display all records, once the user enter his name in SOAP tool.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

accist is a list in your code and your res.Name expecting string and you are trying to assign from list to string which is not possible. You need to get first index of your list item as shown in below code.

```
global class exposewsdl{
    global class requestKT{
        webservice string inputName; 
    }
    global class responseOfWs{
        webservice string name;
        webservice string errorFound;
    }
    webservice static responseOfWs getCaseDetailsFromcsNum(requestKT csNum){
        try{
            List<Opportunity> optyList =New List<Opportunity>();
             List<contact> conList= New List<contact>();
             List<account> accList=New List<account>();

             String searchStr1 = '*'+csNum.inputName+'*';
             String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' +searchStr1  + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  Account (Name),Contact(name),Lead(name)';
            List<List <sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);
            accList = ((List<Account>)searchList[0]);
            conList  = ((List<contact>)searchList[1]);
            optyList = ((List<Opportunity>)searchList[2]);
            responseOfWs res = new responseOfWs();
            res.name= accList[0].name; //First index assigned
            return res;
        }catch(Exception e){
            responseOfWs res = new responseOfWs();
            res.errorFound = e.getMessage();
            return res;
        }
    }

}
```